# sed to add xml line after matching pattern

Tags: unix, sed

i have to add

```
<configuration>
      <jsp-configuration
       display-source-fragment="false"
       x-powered-by="false"/>
    </configuration>
```

after matching this pattern line

```
 <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
```

how i can achieve this using sed command i tried some what like this

```
sed '/connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/a\ \<configuration>\n\<jsp-configuration display-source-fragment="false" x-powered-by="false"/>\n\</configuration> abc.xml
```

Comment: need a newline after the `a\\` and normaly no `\\` needed before `<`

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` will do:

```
awk '/<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"\/>/ {$0=$0"\n<configuration>\n      <jsp-configuration\n       display-source-fragment=\"false\"\n       x-powered-by=\"false\"/>\n    </configuration>"}1' abc.xml
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
<configuration>
      <jsp-configuration
       display-source-fragment="false"
       x-powered-by="false"/>
    </configuration>
```

Or using `sed`

```
sed '/<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"\/>/a <configuration>\n      <jsp-configuration\n       display-source-fragment=\"false\"\n       x-powered-by=\"false\"/>\n    </configuration>' abc.xml
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
<configuration>
      <jsp-configuration
       display-source-fragment="false"
       x-powered-by="false"/>
    </configuration>
```

You are close with your  `sed`, you miss a  `'` at the end and some spaces.